# grab values from view and send to the controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Inside my razor view page I have list of photos. I want to mark photo or photos which will be sent to controller for further manipulation.

How can I grab this values (id (int) of each selected photo) and how to sent this list of integers to the controller using javascript?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).  Also, post your HTML, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnSelecetdPhotos" id="hdnSelecetdPhotosId" value="" />
```

.Then at the "onclick" event of each photo call a javascript/jQuery function and assign their id to the hiddenfield with comma separated.

Then at HttpPost of the action send the hiddenfield name from the argument like :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string hdnSelecetdPhotos)
{
   //Here you can get the all selected photo ids by the "hdnSelecetdPhotos" parameter.
}
```